# Powershell ISE "Illegal characters in path" when piping paths to test-path?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-ise

I have the following script in Powershell **ISE**.

```
cd E:\Data
@"
xxxx.zip
yyyy.zip
"@ -split "`n" | % { echo "'$_'"; test-path -path "$_" -EA Stop }
```

However it always raises error.

```
'xxxx.ZIP'
False
Illegal characters in path.
At line:175 char:27
+ % { echo "'$_'"; test-path <<<<  -path "$_" -EA Stop }
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (E:\Data\xxxx.ZIP:String) [Test-Path], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ItemExistsArgumentError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestPathCommand
```

However, I can run `Test-Path -path xxxx.zip` or just hard code 'xxxx.zip' in the script and it runs fine. What's the problem of piped string?

**Update**

If I change the last script to `% { echo "'$_'"; "test-path -path $_ -EA Stop" }` and copy/paste the output ("`test-path -path xxxx.ZIP -EA Stop`") to the command line. It works.

**Update**

It seems it works in powershell console. An ISE bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the ISE the here-string should be split using a **carriage return followed by a powershell new line**, like this:

```
cd E:\Data
@"
xxxx.zip
yyyy.zip
"@ -split "`r`n" | % { echo "'$_'"; test-path -path "$_" -EA Stop }
```

When using this function:

```
function asciiToHex($a)
{
$b = $a.ToCharArray();
Foreach ($element in $b) {$c = $c + "%#x" + [System.String]::Format("{0:X}",
[System.Convert]::ToUInt32($element)) + ";"}
$c
}
```

to convert the here-string in the ise we get:

```
asciitohex $t
%#x78;%#x78;%#x78;%#x78;%#x2E;%#x7A;%#x69;%#x70;%#xD;%#xA;%#x79;%#x79;%#x79;%#x79;%#x2E;%#x7A;%#x69;%#x70;
```

however in the powershell console we get

```
asciitohex $t
%#x78;%#x78;%#x78;%#x78;%#x2E;%#x7A;%#x69;%#x70;%#xA;%#x79;%#x79;%#x79;%#x79;%#x2E;%#x7A;%#x69;%#x70;
```

Comment: Thanks, this difference is really annoy. Can `-split` accept regular expression so it will work for both environment?

Comment: @NickW Yes it can. I put an example how in my answer. Jon did all the hard work so he deserves the accepted answer here, but feel free to upvote ;-)

Comment: Great catch jon! +1 for comparing in hex.

Answer (score 3):

An example to work in both the ISE and the console using a regular expression with `-split`.

```
cd C:\
@"
xxxx.zip
yyyy.zip
"@ -split "`r`n|`n" | % { echo "'$_'"; test-path -path "$_" -EA Stop }
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that this is exactly the script that you are executing? I can't replicate the problem.

```
NTCs>  @"
>> xxxx.zip
>> yyyy.zip
>> "@ -split "`n"|%{echo "'$_'";test-path -path "$_" -ea stop}
>>
'xxxx.zip'
False
'yyyy.zip'
False
```

**Updated**
To work in ISE and console put the return character with a question sign (0 or 1 ocurrence):

```
  @"
 xxxx.zip
 yyyy.zip
 "@ -split "`r?`n"|%{echo "'$_'";test-path -path "$_" -ea stop}
```

Comment: I am running these using Powershell ISE. Did you try it in ISE?

Comment: you are right, it happend only in ISE. It must be because the editor put that invicible character at the end of every line. Thank god the console don't do the same, ;D